# How could I pass value from textbox to itself event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

How could I pass value from textbox to itself event?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" onblur="SendRequest()">this_text_I_want_to_put_as_param_to_SendRequest</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox 
    runat="server" 
    ID="txtEmail" 
    onblur="SendRequest(this.value)">
    this_text_I_want_to_put_as_param_to_SendRequest
</asp:TextBox>
```